# lowest superordinate of two concepts in a taxonomy

Tags: algorithm, taxonomy

How to find the lowest superordinate of two concepts in an efficient way?
The lowest superordinate of two concepts in a taxonomy means the most specific common ancestor of the two concepts. For example, in the following picture of a taxonomy, how find the most common ancestor of sense 1 and sense 2?

[image: Taxonomy]

BTW, I found this question in Roberto Navigli's survey of word sense disambiguation. He didn't mention how to compute the superordinate.

Answer (score 1):

You could go up the hierarchy from the `Sense 1` side and mark all of those nodes as ancestors of `Sense 1`.  Then go up the `Sense 2` side and check each ancestor to see if you marked it as an ancestor of `Sense 1`.  The first one you find would be the lowest superordinate or most specific common ancestor.

In your picture, it would be the root node no matter which senses you start from.

Comment: Sense 1 may have more than one parents. Do I need to mark every path from sense 1 to the root, and match them to each path of sense 2? Is there any other more efficient method?

Comment: @jerry_sjtu: if your taxonomy is not a hierarchy, then there need not be a well-defined lowest superordinate. For example, suppose A and B are both parents of X, and also both parents of Y. Then which of A and B is the lowest superordinate?

Comment: Yes, in the simple method I described you would mark every path from sense 1 to the root.  There certainly may be a more efficient method, but it really depends on your application.  It could be faster to compute every lowest superordinate for every sense in one pass instead of doing it as needed, assuming you would eventually need to compute each one anyway.

Comment: @jerry_sjtu - It appears I may have misunderstood your comment.  This method would not work if Sense 1 can have more than one direct parent.  (Or perhaps you only meant that its parent can have a parent, etc...?).

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor contains pointers to more efficient algorithms for the least common ancestor problem in the (usual) case where we have a tree, so every node has one parent, except for the root node, which has no parent. These algorithms can answer queries in constant time, after linear time pre-processing of the tree.

I do not know if any of these algorithms would generalise to the case where you can have more than one parent. It looks like the obvious generalisations would amount to deleting links in your tree to make sure that, while still connected, every node had at most one parent.